# How do I set my screen resolution back to 1366x768?

Tags: release-hera

I accidentally set my screen resolution to 800x600 in a 720p laptop screen, and when I tried to revert it, I can't reach the buttons because my laptop screen was too small. The answers that I tried were for Loki. Is there a version of this for Hera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xrandr cli-tool for that.

1. Open Terminal by `⌘ + T`
2. Type `xrandr` to see available screen modes

```
elementary@elementary:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 800 x 600, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 connected primary 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x962      60.00 +
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     59.98    59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89    59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79    60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1280x768      59.87    59.99  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32*   56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94
```

3. Apply mode you want

```
elementary@elementary:~$ xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1280x800
```

4. Done

p.s.
it should work for most of the Linux distribution